# Image animating sequence

Tags: android

i am new to this platform... I am having 3 png images and i want those images to run in a loop how can i do that...I need know creation of both xml and the java activity codezzz too...plz help on that

Answer (score 0):

Probably use an imageswitcher. As far as code examples go, you can pretty much Google that. [Here's the doc on imageswitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html).

Comment: Hi dudez...GudMrng... can u give me some example code regarding this image loop animation